# Converse.js render into a container

Tags: javascript, xmpp, chat, openfire, converse.js

Is it possible to configure Converse.js to render it's boxes into custom `div` containers instead of adding them to the body of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by writing a [converse.js plugin](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/development.html#writing-a-converse-js-plugin) in which you override the [insertIntoPage](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/blob/049782651c2c0be663c553d750fa60e8244afa61/converse.js#L1369) method of `ChatBoxView`.

Refer to the plugin documentation I linked to above. In short, it would look something like this:

```
// The following line registers your plugin.
converse_api.plugins.add('myplugin', {

    overrides: {
        // If you want to override some function or a Backbone model or
        // view defined inside converse, then you do that under this
        // "overrides" namespace.    
        ChatBoxView: {
            insertIntoPage: function (type, status_message, jid) {
                // XXX Your custom code comes here.
                // The standard code looks as follows:
                this.$el.insertAfter(converse.chatboxviews.get("controlbox).$el);
                return this;
            }
        },
    }
```

**UPDATE: Since recent versions of converse.js, the method to override is instead [_ensureElement](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/blob/21bc95a9f37948c18533722323f053ffa7d4225a/src/converse-core.js#L1595) and not `insertIntoPage`.**