# Customize converse.js to create desktop chat layout (like web.whatsapp.com)

Tags: angularjs, chat, converse.js

Can anyone give some idea on how to go about customizing the `converse.js` file in angularjs so that it can be displayed as a web page rather than its predefined toggle functionality?

Please give some idea about how to initiate with the customization of the .js file.

Thanx.

[image: This is how the basic page would look(already coded).]

This is how the basic page would look(already coded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be able to do it without customizing the existing .js files, but you won't be able to do it without writing Javascript.

You'll have to [write a plugin for converse.js](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/development.html#writing-a-converse-js-plugin) that overrides and extends its functionality.

Your goal is very similar to the question asked here: [Converse.js render into a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475755/converse-js-render-into-a-container/35226116#35226116)

And the answer is pretty much the same as well, except that you will need to not only override the ChatBoxView but also the ControlBoxView to render it in the correct place.